# C# - Visual Studio Package - Place a button on the Resolve Conflict window

Tags: conflict, vsix, resolve

I am developing a Visual Studio Pacakge. I would like to place my button on the Resolve Conflict window next to the "Keep Local Version" button. It would be also good if i could place my button on this window somehow somewhere.

[Resolve Conflict window](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/_img/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts/ic612247.png)

I found this source file that contains a lot of IDs (GUIDs).

[vsshlids.h](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/blob/master/Common/Include/vsshlids.h)

I tried all of the IDs from the Team Foundation section.

```
// Team Foundation Client standard menu
#define IDM_MENU_TEAM_FOUNDATION_CLIENT     0x700
#define IDM_MENU_PROJECT_CONTEXT_MENU       0x707
#define IDM_TEAM_PROJECT_SETTINGS_MENU      0x708
#define IDM_TEAM_SERVER_SETTINGS_MENU       0x709

// Team Foundation Client Toolbar Group
#define IDG_TEAM_FOUNDATION_CLIENT_TOOLBAR  0x701

// Commands on the Team menu for projects that require project context
#define IDG_MENU_PROJECT_CONTEXT            0x702
// Commands on the Team menu shared by tools (e.g. Properties)
#define IDG_SHARED_COMMANDS                 0x703
// Tool-specific commands on the Team menu
#define IDG_TOOL_COMMANDS                   0x704

// Team Project Settings Cascade Menu Group
#define IDG_TEAM_PROJECT_SETTINGS_COMMANDS  0x705
// Team Server Settings Cascade Menu Group
#define IDG_TEAM_SERVER_SETTINGS_COMMANDS   0x706

// Commands on the TE context menu for projects that require project context
#define IDG_CTXT_PROJECT_CONTEXT 0x710
```

but the first four places my button in the Team group in the menu bar and the others do nothing. It is my fault: i didn't find them or i implented them wrongly.

Is it possible to place my button on the Resolve Conflict windows somehow?

Thank you for your help in advance,

Balazs